# How to get data between <td></td> with HtmlXpathSelector in Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy, html-table, pydev

I want to scraping one site 118.69.35.146/sjc/ for testing SCRAPY framework. I use HTMLXPathSelector to choose, the code snippet for this task as below:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = sel.select('//table[@id="grv_GiaVangUpdate"]/tr')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = FinanceItem()
        item['buy'] = site.select('//td[3]/text()').extract()
        item['sell'] = site.select('//td[4]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I hope to get the text data value between  and .

But the results in JSON file output I just got null value for total 16 nodes.

```
[{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []},
{"sell": [], "buy": []}]
```

Would any expert here please check this code for me and teach me which point I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the page and testing the query in Firepath I see that it should work.

Verify that you actually get the same page: put a `pdb`/`ipdb` breakpoint (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`) after `sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)` and see what's inside `response`. Then step by step debug your program to see where and why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should always test the xpath with the scrapy shell (`scrapy shell 'http://118.69.35.146/sjc/'`) ant not only with others tools.

For this site, for the same element, firefox has something like `<td align="center">34,870</td>` while scrapy has `<td align="center"><font face="Times New Roman" color="Black" size="3">34,870</font></td>`. So you want `'//td[3]/font/text()'` or maybe better `'//td[3]//text()'`.

But you will get other problem... When you do `site.select('//td[3]/text()').extract()`, you are searching all the tree and not just inside `'//table[@id="grv_GiaVangUpdate"]/tr'` as, I suppose, you want. You should use `'.//td[3]/text()'`, with a point at begin.

Note: select is deprecated, use xpath() instead.